# change html output doxygen link

Tags: doxygen

I am working on a project that is heavily documented with doxygen.
In a UI I have a list of all the classes available - I would like to be able to open the right documentation page of the class I select. In order to do that I need an easy to read link, so I can dynamically build it and run it.

Is it there any way I can control the generated link of the html file? Because the ones I have right now are impossible do be built dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Doxygen's tag file mechanism for that (see GENERATE_TAGFILE in the config file).

A tag file is a reasonably easy to understand and parse XML file that basically lists all symbols in your project, with for each symbol the corresponding (relative) URL to the documentation.

So you could parse the tag file from your UI to resolve the links to the doxygen generated documentation in a robust way.

Comment: mmmmm I am not really sure how to do that but thanks for the tip! I am gonna look into it thanks!